# The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

I am developing an MVC 5 application with EF 6 database first approach. Now I want my DbContext to access multiple databases based on different Users. For that matter I generated a connection string in Web.Config file as:

```
string str = u.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).First().ConnStr;
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");          
ConnectionStringSettings c = new ConnectionStringSettings();    
c.ConnectionString = str;
c.Name = u.Users.Where(x => x.ConnStr == str).First().DbName;
c.ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
section.ConnectionStrings.Add(c);
configuration.Save();
```

The connection string generated in config file is:

```
<add name="Awais123" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Awais123;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And the Connection String generated by EF when I made EDMX is:

```
<add name="ABCEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.awais.csdl|res://*/Models.awais.ssdl|res://*/Models.awais.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Awais;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Then I overloaded my Entities constructor as:

```
public ABCEntities(string nameorConnString) : base(nameorConnString) {}
```

And the default Constructor is:

```
public ABCEntities() : base("name=ABCEntities") {}
```

Now I declare another DbContext class in another .cs file to generate the database as:

```
public partial class NewDbGen : DbContext
{
     public NewDbGen(string nameorConnString): base(nameorConnString)
     { Database.Create(); }
}
```

I am calling the DbContext objects as:

```
private static string str = u.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).First().ConnStr;
private NewDbGen de = new NewDbGen(str); // for creating a new database
private ABCEntities db = new AbcEntities(str); // my original Entites.. and all my controllers use these entites for all queries
```

Now all this runs successfully and database is created in SQL Server. But later when I tried to query on that database an error occured in:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
}
```

And it throws an error

> The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was
>   generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First
>   development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not
>   remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use
>   Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity
>   Framework connection string is included in the app.config or
>   web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own
>   DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not
>   some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the
>   base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more
>   about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity
>   Framework documentation here:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

What can I do? I have to use single DbContext for all User Databases and same object of ABCEntities i.e. "db" to access database in controller methods.
I have already looked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865627/using-multiple-databases-with-single-dbcontext-and-entites-and-generating-conn-s) DbFactory method, but the same error occured.

I want to make a Single Instance Multi-Tenant application

Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are using Database-First approach and you use edmx, then using [`OnModelCreating`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=entity-framework-6.2.0) makes no sense.

To have a single instance application that uses database per tenant strategy, you should:

- Use a single dbcontext class for all tenants
- Add an overload to your dbcontext constructor that accept connnectionstring
- create a database for each tenant
- create connectionstring at run-time based on your tenant detection strategy
- create an instance of dbcontext passing the connectionstring that you created at run-time based on your tenant detection strategy

Comment: Lae but still it could be helpful to someone.